# AZure DataBricks - Large CSV file field validation

Tags: python, azure, csv, databricks, data-cleaning

I am new to DataBricks. My task is is to read a number of large CSV files (upto 1 gig in size) and validate and clean all fields ready for a polybase read into an Azure DW. The files are stored in blob.

I thought that DatBricks and Python  would be an approach that would yield sensible performance.

I have used the example QuickStart shown below as a starting point:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-portal

I want to perform a number of cleaning replacements on every field and also run a Regex, to filter out any other unwanted characters and finally trim to remove trailing spaces. I have included a test example snippet below which gives a flavour of the type of validation I wish to perform. This example uses a udf to translate a value, and then regex to filter unwanted characters, on the example shown in the link.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

def udf_clean (s):
  return (f.translate(s,'3','B'))

df.filter(df.category=='Housing').select(df[1],f.trim(f.regexp_replace(udf_clean(df[1]),'(\d+)',''))).show()
```

What I cant find out is how I can perform these translations on the whole dataframe. I would like to cleans the whole dataframe in one pass. As it is vector based I feel I shouldn't have to iterate through it row at a time , but just perform some sort of operation on the whole. I understand how to iterate a row, as in

```
`for row in df.rdd.collect():
     do_something(row)`
```

..but I feel I should be able to do something more efficiently for the whole set of fields.
Is this thinking correct, and has anyone got any examples please? Many Thanks, Richard

## Resultant code but not the answer

I have not found an answer to this question , but I though I would post my code which as you will see is not elegant but works .

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, udffrom pyspark.sql.functions import translate, udf

from pyspark.sql.functions import trim, udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction


def udf_regexclean(s):
  return trim(regexp_replace(s,'([^\p{L}\p{Nd} ''@.():_*\-&+\/,])',''))

def udf_regexReplace(s):
  return regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(s,'£','GBR'),'’',''),'  ',''),"'t",''),'É', 'E')


df1=df.select( udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[0 ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[1   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[2   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[3   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[4   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[5   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[6   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[7   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[8   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[9   ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[10  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[11  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[12  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[13  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[14  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[15  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[16  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[17  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[18  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[19  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[20  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[21  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[22  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[23  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[24  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[25  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[26  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[27  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[28  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[29  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[30  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[31  ]))
,udf_regexclean(udf_regexReplace(df[32  ]))
             )
df2=df1.withColumn('ScrapedFilename',lit(blob_filename))
```

Richard

Answer (score 1):

As sample, I created a simple sample to realize your needs, not to replace, just to create a new dataframe via apply an UDF function on the RDD of an old dataframe.

First I created a simple dataframe as the code and figure below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(df)
display(sparkDF)
```

[image]

Then, to define a function for each row, as the code and figure below.

```
def udf_clean(row):
  return (row[0] > 0 and True or False, row[1]+2, row[2]*2, row[3]**4)
new_rdd = sparkDF.rdd.map(lambda row: udf_clean(row))
new_sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(new_rdd, list('ABCD'))
display(new_sparkDF)
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks , but what I am after is a design where I don't have to specify each field in the row in the udf ( there may be 100 fields), as I want to perform the  (multiple) replaces and regex on all fields. Is there any syntax to specify all field rows ?